# Selinux is preventing to start Tomcat

Tags: linux, redhat, tomcat, systemd, selinux

I have a problem when I launch tomcat on RHEL 8:

```
[root@TEST ~]# systemctl restart tomcat.service
Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status tomcat.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@TEST ~]#
```

In journalctl I can see:

```
-- Unit tomcat.service has begun starting up.
Dec 08 14:58:30 TEST systemd[3869]: tomcat.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Dec 08 14:58:30 TEST systemd[3869]: tomcat.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /mnt/efs/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh: Permission denied
-- Subject: Process /mnt/efs/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- The process /mnt/efs/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh could not be executed and failed.
--
-- The error number returned by this process is 13.
Dec 08 14:58:30 TEST systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
Dec 08 14:58:30 TEST systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 08 14:58:30 TEST systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat Server.
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has failed
```

The problem is only when SELinux is in enforcing mode, when i turn off Selinux tomcat starts correctly.

Rights and context for catalina.sh file:

```
[root@TEST ~]# ls -lZ /mnt/efs/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh
-rwxr-x--x. 1 tomcat tomcat system_u:object_r:unconfined_exec_t:s0 23567 Oct  7 09:57 /mnt/efs/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh
[root@TEST ~]#
```

It seems that SELinux is blocking systemd to start the script from this path, but don't know how change it.

Do you have any idea? Someone had a same issue on with Selinux?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to fix the file context on the directories where your application is located.

This is usually accomplished by using the `semanage -a -t "correct context" "dir"` and `restorecon -Rv "directory"`. The following links will help you:

- https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-tomcat_selinux/
- https://noobient.com/2017/10/02/selinux-woes-with-tomcat-on-centos-74/

Some SELinux bools might also need to be tweaked depending on what exactly does your application do.